# RxJava: remove element from list

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have tried various operators for iterating objects using `map`, `concatMap`,`all` but i am not able to remove element from my list.

Here is a piece of code:

```
  Observable.fromIterable(selectedJobs)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // Added this from one answer in SO. but still no resolution.
            .all(homeJob -> {

                if (!homeJob.isCanCloseJob()) {
                    selectedJobs.remove(homeJob); // <- this is what causing Exception
                    //toast message
                } else {
                    //do something
                }

                return true;
            })
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Boolean aBoolean) {

                    baseRealm.executeTransaction(realm -> realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(selectedJobs));

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    AppLogger.e(tag, throwable.getMessage());
                 // throws Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
                }
            });
```

All I want is to check for condition then remove object from list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In functional programming you are working with streams. Instead of removing an item from the initial input you have to filter the stream itself and pass the filtered list to the consumer.

Seems like this is what you are looking for:

```
Observable.fromIterable(listOfElements)
          .filter(element -> {
              if (element.isValid()) {
                  // do some action with valid `element`
                  // NOTE: this action would be performed with each valid element
                  return true;
              } else {
                  // `element` is not valid, perform appropriate action
                  // NOTE: this action would be performed for each invalid element
                  return false;
              }
          })
          .toList() // collect all the filtered elements into a List
          .subscribe(
                  filteredElements -> /* use `filteredElements` which is List<Element> */, 
                  throwable -> /* perform appropriate action with this `throwable`*/)
          );
```

Comment: i tried with `filter` operator but I wanted all filtered objects and that's what you're doing with `toList()` function which will return filtered list in `onSuccess`. Thanks. I am accepting this answer